# New OneNote note via WP8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, onenote

Is there any way of programmatically adding a new note to OneNote via a Windows Phone 8 app? I know I can't interact directly with the OneNote app, but wondering if there's a way to add directly to the `Personal (Web)` file on SkyDrive via an API or sending an email or whatever. I've done some searching and I'm guessing not, but can't hurt to ask, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect so SkyDrive via the [Live Connect API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx). There's a tutorial for interacting with SkyDrive from Windows Phone [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/SkyDrive_-_How_to_upload_content_on_Windows_Phone). I've not tried interacting with a OneNote file but if it's on SkyDrive, it should be accessible.

Having said that, OneNote uses a proprietary format and I'm not sure if there's an API you can call on the phone to create OneNote pages programmatically. It does [have an interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx) which you could look into but it seems you might need to do that server side and interact via a web service from your app.